# Can someone explain how the standard error range was determine and how 68% expected was determined?

Tags: statistics

I understand the other aspects just not how the range from 2.52 to 3.68 was achieved, and a 68% expected.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Via integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area underneath the curve between the two outermost dashed lines is about $68\%$ of the area underneath the entire curve.

You'll also find it helpful to remember the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), which reminds you that $1,2,3$ standard deviations from the mean consume about $68\%, 95\%, 99.7\%$ of the area under the normal distribution.

Comment: Also realized it's just the mean + or - the standard error so 3.1+.58= 3.68 and 3.1-.58=2.52.